# PHP Function to know the next value of loop?

Tags: php

Let's say I have this foreach loop:

```
foreach ($lists as $list) {
    if (next list item == "test") {
         echo "the next $list item equals 'test'";
    }
}
```

I hope you get what i'm aiming at from the code.

Thanks,

Comment: two people removed their answers? why?

Comment: One because it didn't work on associative arrays; the other probably because it says the same thing as some of the already present answers

Comment: Isn't it easier to use a for loop and just offset the counter?

Comment: @nico Not if the array is associative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php).

Bear in mind this advances the internal pointer, so to rewind it back, use [`prev()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php).

However, in the example below, I used [`current()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) which gets the current pointer of an array. `foreach()` seems to increment it once in the body of the construct.

[Konforce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259778/konforce) came up with this idea originally.

The last blank is `NULL`, which is good (there is no next member). :)

```
$lists = range('a', 'f');

foreach($lists as &$value) {
   $next = current($lists);
   echo 'value: ' . $value . "\n" . 'next: ' . $next . "\n\n";
}

unset($next, $value);
```

#### Output

```
value: a
next: b

value: b
next: c

value: c
next: d

value: d
next: e

value: e
next: f

value: f
next:
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/OAFYuCw0).

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't play nice with the `foreach` construct. I think to get it to work, it looks something like this: `foreach ($a as &$v) { $next = current($a); }` Play around with it to see for sure. Note that the manual warns against mixing those array pointer functions with a `foreach`.

Comment: @konorce I had a crack and this seems to work. It could probably be more elegant though :)

Comment: @alex, interesting solution. You are right that the `foreach` is clobbering the pointer. (To test, call `each` many times in the same loop... it still works.) I would be hesitant to use it though because I believe it relies on undocumented functionality. The manual says explicitly "Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it."

Comment: @konorce Hmm, you are right. But resetting it will ruin my solution, of course.

Comment: @alex, if they ever "fix" it. It will also ruin your solution ;)

Comment: @Leigh @konorce @downvoter I changed it to `current()`. It just returns the current pointer. So there should not be a chance of any internal pointer being incremented :)

Comment: @alex, it's probably less risky to use `current`. However, perhaps the PHP gods would change the `foreach` to not modify that pointer at all, in which case `current` would always point to the first one. Although, I doubt they would change such functionality for little gain, knowing that it could break code. PS: You may want to `unset()` the reference after the loop is done just to avoid the pesky lingering reference side effect.

Answer (score 2):

For an index based array, it's simple. Use a `for` loop or make use of `$i => $val` when looping.

For other arrays, you can do something like:

```
$current = current($lists);
while ($current !== false)
{
        $next = next($lists);

        echo "$current => $next\n";

        $current = $next;
}
```

although if your array contains the literal value false, it won't work. You will also need to `reset` to loop through again.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate current/next item:

```
<?php
    $lists = range('a', 'f');

    foreach ($lists as $next) {
        if($list !== NULL) {
            if ($next == "test") {
                echo "the next $next item equals 'test'";
            }

            echo 'current: ' . $list . ', next: ' . $next . "\n";
        }
        $list = $next;
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
current: a, next: b
current: b, next: c
current: c, next: d
current: d, next: e
current: e, next: f
```

Comment: I didn't get your answer... it checks if the current item equals "test" as $next is your current item

Comment: That test array looks familiar :P